# SQLite3 Operational Error Help using tkinter

Tags: python, sqlite, user-interface, tkinter

I am fairly new to using SQLite3, and I am having trouble with my gui when I try to run the program. The error it shows is:

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM Info WHERE oid = ' + user_id)
sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input
```

I've been following along a [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EAs3gr9mC9g) tutorial on how to update a user's information such as their username and password. In the main AppClass, I used:

```
self.frame_data = { "userID": "",  
                    "passcode": ""}
```

as a way to grab the information from an entry box in one frame, and use it in another frame. What I want to try and do is use the user's id number to access their information, and have the entry box all filled in with their current information in the EditUser frame. I've tried having both userID and passcode be set to tk.StringVar() but I also get errors when I do it this way, since I can't concatenate a str with a StringVar. I apologize if there are any mistakes with the code as I am new to SQLite3.
This is my code:

```
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import font as tkfont
    import sqlite3
    
    with sqlite3.connect('user_info.db') as db:
        c = db.cursor()
    
    #c.execute('CREATE TABLE Info(
    #                    Name text,
    #                    Passcode text
    #                    )')
    db.commit()
    db.close()
    
    class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family = 'Garamond', size = 18, weight = "bold", slant = "italic")
    
            self.frame_data = {"userID": "",
                               "passcode": ""
                               }
    
            #container we'll stack frames on top of each other, then the one we want to
            #visible will be raised above the others
            container = tk.Frame(self)
            container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = "True")
            container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
            container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
          
            self.frames = {}
            for F in (StartPage, PageOne, Account, EditUser):
                page_name = F.__name__
                frame = F(parent = container, controller = self)
                self.frames[page_name] = frame
    
                #put all of the pages in the same location;
                #the one on the top of the stacking order
                #will be the one that is visible
                frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
    
            self.show_frame("StartPage")
    
        def show_frame(self, page_name):
            '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
            frame = self.frames[page_name]
            frame.tkraise()
            frame.configure(background = 'teal')  
class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        label = tk.Label(self, text = "Sample App", font = controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side = "top")

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Go to Page One", bg = "green", fg = "white", width = 15, height = 3,
                            command = lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text = "Go to Page Two", bg = "green", fg = "white", width = 15,
                        height = 4, command = lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))

        Exitbutton = tk.Button(self, text="Exit", width = 8, height = 3, command = self.Exit)

        button1.place(x = 200, y = 200)
        button2.place(x = 600, y = 200)
        Exitbutton.place(x = 350, y = 330)

    def Exit(self):
        self.controller.destroy()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text = "This is Page One", font = controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side = "top")

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Start Page",
                            command = lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text = "Account",
                            command = lambda: controller.show_frame("Account"))
        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()

class Account(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        #Labels
        u_name_label = tk.Label(self, text = "Enter User's name")
        u_name_label.place(x = 200, y = 200)

        p_code_label = tk.Label(self, text = "Enter Passcode")
        p_code_label.place(x = 200, y = 300)

        #Text Box 
        self.u_name = tk.Entry(self)
        self.u_name.place(x = 350, y = 200)

        self.p_code = tk.Entry(self)
        self.p_code.place(x = 350, y = 300)

        self.userID = tk.Entry(self, textvariable = self.controller.frame_data["userID"])
        self.userID.pack()

        submit = tk.Button(self, text = "Submit", command = lambda: self.submit())
        submit.place(x = 400, y = 350)

        show = tk.Button(self, text = "Show Info", command = lambda: self.query())
        show.place(x = 300, y = 100)
        
        select = tk.Button(self, text = "Edit User", command = lambda: controller.show_frame("EditUser"))
        select.pack()

    def submit(self):
        with sqlite3.connect('user_info.db') as db:
            c = db.cursor()

        #insert into table
        c.execute("INSERT INTO Info VALUES (:u_name, :p_code)",
                  {
                      'u_name': self.u_name.get(),
                      'p_code': self.p_code.get()
                  })

        #commit changes
        db.commit()
        #close connection
        db.close()
        #clear textboxes
        self.u_name.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.p_code.delete(0, tk.END)

    def query(self):
        with sqlite3.connect('user_info.db') as db:
            c = db.cursor()

        c.execute("SELECT *, oid FROM Info")
        records = c.fetchall()
        #print(records)
        
        #Loop through results
        print_records = ''

        for record in records:
            print_records += str(record[0]) + " " + str(record[1]) +  '\n'
        
        query_label = tk.Label(self, text = print_records)
        query_label.place(x = 600, y = 200)


        db.commit()
        db.close()

class EditUser(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        with sqlite3.connect('user_info.db') as db:
            c = db.cursor()
        
        
        user_id = self.controller.frame_data["userID"]
        label = tk.Label(self, textvariable = user_id)
        label.pack()

        c.execute('SELECT * FROM Info WHERE oid = ' + user_id)
        records = c.fetchall()
        
        u_name_label = tk.Label(self, text = "User's name")
        u_name_label.place(x = 200, y = 200)

        p_code_label = tk.Label(self, text = "User's Passcode")
        p_code_label.place(x = 200, y = 300)

        self.u_name_edit = tk.Entry(self)
        self.u_name_edit.place(x = 350, y = 200)

        self.p_code_edit = tk.Entry(self)
        self.p_code_edit.place(x = 350, y = 300)

        save = tk.Button(self, text = "Save Edits", command = lambda: self.update())
        save.place(x=400, y = 350)

        #Loop through results
        for record in records:
            self.u_name_edit.insert(0, record[0])
            self.p_code_edit.insert(0, record[1])

    def update(self):
        with sqlite3.connect('user_info.db') as db:
            c = db.cursor()

        record_id = self.controller.frame_data["userID"]
        c.execute("""UPDATE Info SET
            Name = :first,
            Passcode = :passcode
            
            WHERE oid = :oid""",
            {
                'first': self.u_name_edit.get(),
                'passcode': self.p_code_edit.get(),

                'oid': record_id
             })

        db.commit()
        db.close()

        self.u_name_edit.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.p_code_edit.delete(0, tk.END)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.title("Sample App")
    app.geometry("800x500")
    app.mainloop()
```

**EDIT**
I replaced the textvariable parameter *userID* in the SampleApp class to tk.StringVar() and changed the c.execute command to `c.execute('SELECT * FROM Info WHERE oid = ?' ,(user_id,))` and got this error:

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM Info WHERE oid = ?' ,(user_id,))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

Comment: Firstly use `c.execute('SELECT * FROM Info WHERE oid = ?' ,(user_id,))` and then paste the entire error code.

Comment: Make sure `user_id` contains a valid value.

Comment: I don't see any code that assigns to `self.controller.frame_data["userID"]`

Comment: The `textvariable` parameter of `tk.Entry` should be a `StringVar` object, not an ordinary string.

Comment: @Barmar How can I modify it so that user_id can have the value from the  Account class?

Comment: @CoolCloud I changed the c,execute line and changed the textvariable parameter of tk.Emtry, and posted the new error I got

Comment: I think it means `user_id` is `''` or `None`. Use `print(user_id)` to find out.

Comment: It prints out `PY_VAR0`

Comment: Use `user_id.get()`.

Comment: Wouldn't that return empty since I already have `userID = self.controller.frame_data["userID"]` which is getting the input from the entry box from `class Account`?